# SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol Unable to establish SSL connection (windows)

Tags: ssl, cmd, openssl, window, wget

```
wget -A pdf -m -p -E -k -K -nd https://www.ceratizit.com/
```

I am trying to run this command on **Windows** CMD but I keep gettign an error that:

SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc                                                                             syswgetrc = C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32/etc/wgetrc                                                                  --2021-07-07 10:03:45--  https://www.ceratizit.com/                                                                     Resolving www.ceratizit.com... 2.16.128.209, 2.16.128.225                                                               Connecting to www.ceratizit.com|2.16.128.209|:443... connected.                                                         OpenSSL: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol                                            Unable to establish SSL connection.

The same command works on linux but not on **Windows**. What can I try?

GNU Wget 1.11.4

Comment: Please include the full output (for the debug information) and also include the output of `wget --version` in your question.

Comment: please see the updated qs @SteffenUllrich

Comment: `GNU Wget 1.11.4`?  That's from 2008.  How old is your OpenSSL?